# Using node webkit to build console application

Tags: node.js

I wanted to build myself a distributable for a node js console application. Below is the package.json

```
  {
  "main": "index.js",
  "window": {
    "show": false
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "winston": "2.2.0"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-nw-builder": "^2.0.3",
    "nw-builder": "^2.2.6"
  }
}
```

I am using grunt nw builder to build excutable. Below is the Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        nwjs: {
            options: {
                version: '0.14.6',
                buildDir: './build', // Where the build version of my NW.js app is saved
                platforms: ['win64'] // These are the platforms that we want to build
            },
            src: './**/*',
             // Your NW.js app
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nw-builder');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['nwjs']);
};
```

After I run grunt , I do get the binary build {app-name}.exe. in win64 dir.
However when I launch this exe (either through console or through windows) , I do not see anything in console. However I do see the app executable as running process in process explorer. The application spits out a logfile and a few other json files as output, I dont see these files either.

What am I doing wrong .. (Index.js is a pure js file). Is there something different that needs to done, that I am missing out on?